# "pyenv versions" and "python -V" showing different versions

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.8, pyenv

I need to use python 3.8. I installed it using the following command:

```sh
pyenv install 3.8.1
```

Now the output of `pyenv versions` is:

```sh
  system
* 3.8.1 (set by /Users/username/.pyenv/version)
```

Output of `python -V`:

```sh
Python 2.7.16
```

Why are they different?

Comment: Does the output of `python3 -V` match your expectations? On most Unix systems, `python` is the system Python 2 interpreter, and `python3` is the system Python 3 interpreter.

Answer (score 7):

Try `eval "$(pyenv init --path)"`. That worked for me.

Comment: When I type this at a command prompt in powershell on windows it says 'eval' is not a recognized name of a cmdlet.  Where should I type this?

Comment: This is a unix based command. This works on Linux or MacOS.

Answer (score 2):

I had the exact same issue after installing oh-my-zsh.
What solved it for me was:

1. Add pyenv to the plugins list on `.zshrc`:

   ```
   plugins=(git pyenv)
   ```
2. Almost at the top of the file, just under these lines:

   ```
   # Path to your oh-my-zsh installation.
   export ZSH="$HOME/.oh-my-zsh"
   ```

   I added these lines:

   ```
   export PYENV_ROOT="$HOME/.pyenv"
   export PATH="$PYENV_ROOT/bin:$PATH"
   eval "$(pyenv init --path)"
   ```

And then I relaunched the terminal and everything was fine! (that is, the python version was the same)